# hp proliant DL 180 G6 P410 cant enter raid bios

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant

Given this HP Server with P410i raid controller. It doesn't see any attached disks most likely because they are not defined in the RAID bios and I don't see a way to enter there. I have tried F8,F10,F12,CTRL+S repeatedly. There is not even a suggestion when it loads the raid firmware how to go in there.

This is an older server version which doesn't have the HP iLo. I tried the firmware upgrade disks but it just keep rebooting instead of upgrading anything:

http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx

Any suggestions how to enter the raid bios?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You already have the Support Pack for ProLiant DVD, so instead of using it to upgrade firmware, choose the "HP Smart Storage Administrator", which will take you into a GUI that will allow you to configure the array.

Forget using the limited BIOS menu. It's not worth the effort.